# Connecting external office to home LAN - thick glass

Tags: networking, wireless-networking

I have an external office I am trying to get internet to.

I have setup a wired access point at the nearest point inside the main property, however there is then 2 triple glazed windows between that point and the office itself. I have attached a diagram of the current speeds experienced.

[image: Setup]

What setups could I use to ensure good internet in the office area? It is a rental so ideally drilling would be good to avoid. I guess a repeater on each side of each glass (but seems quite excessive!)

Comment: Have you tried using the 2.4ghz for more penetration power? And a powerline adapter? https://www.tp-link.com/us/powerline/ & https://www.nytimes.com/wirecutter/reviews/best-powerline-networking-kit/ & https://www.netgear.com/home/wired/powerline/

Comment: Channel 11 on the router and 2.4Ghz are the strongest - try it but it will probably only help incrementally. You might need a stronger router on both sides.

Comment: @harrymc unless the neighbours are using channel 11

Comment: @Gantendo: That's a good point - the problem could also partially be interference from the neighbors that is strongest near the office. That can be verified by related products, or even just by using the phone. The poster could also try the other best channels at 1 and 6.

Comment: Lifting your router off the floor could help, as could bringing it closer to the Window and closer towards the person taking the picture - ie getting closer to "line of site" between the devices.    Its not clear what make and model router you are using from the picture, but 300 megabit implies its failly cheap / low end 802.11n gear.   Better quality routers (and receivers) can make a massive difference to coverage even on the same band.  I agree with @gantendo about powerline adaptors or similar if they work (they are hit and miss, but great if they do work).

Comment: Directional antennas - and maybe antennas attached to the glass at each location (or both!) could help.   That said, I wonder if your glass is low E glass - this apparently attenuates the signal quite badly.  (If it is regular, not Low E Glass, look at getting WIFI that supports the 5 gig band - apparently regular glasses impact on 5 gig spectrum is not that bad and its a lot less congested)

Comment: A double edged solution - If you can tap into the power strung on those outside lights, you may be able to put a repeater outdoors to relay the signals between the 2 locations.  (I don't generally like repeaters, but Ubiquity make some not-trivial-to-learn but decent prosumer gear - including outdoor gear.  Realistically though if you go the Ubiquity route you would want to replace any WIFI routers with Ubiquity AP's, so the price could add up.

Comment: On the other extreme,  you might be able to make a "cantenna" (ie a cheap highly directional antenna/wave guide often made from things like cans, pots or pringles cans - Google it)  If you use a USB WIFI receiver as the focal point of a cantenna, and have the USB WIFI received connected via a USB cable to a laptop or computer you can aim it from the office computer to your router.